# Selenium Webdriver - Firefox submitting forms where the window is behind another window returns blank result

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

On this website: "uk.burberry.com" there is a search field at the top with a search button to search items. When I search with one firefox window open it works, however when I search when there is more than one firefox window, all the firefox windows behind the firefox window infront of the screen returns a blank result page.

I don't have this problem when using Chrome driver. Is there a issue with firefox driver not allowing to submit forms when they're are not infront of the screen?

I also used both click() and submit() and making sure the button is enabled before hand. When the firefox windows in the background click the search button it goes off to another page giving me this really long URL as the result: *http://uk.burberry.com/burberry/views/listing/searchResults.jsp?_dyncharset=UTF-8&frmSearch_txtQuery=&_D%3AfrmSearch_txtQuery=+&%2Fatg%2Fcommerce%2Fsearch%2Fcatalog%2FQueryFormHandler.errorURL=%2Fburberry%2Fviews%2Flisting%2FsearchResults.jsp&_D%3A%2Fatg%2Fcommerce%2Fsearch%2Fcatalog%2FQueryFormHandler.errorURL=+&start=1&_D%3Astart=+&_DARGS=%2Fburberry%2Fincludes%2FpageStart.jsp.frmSearch*

Thanks

Comment: How are you getting the screenshot, or are you saying the actual page doesn't load?

Comment: Hello, I just look at it running. So I just tested again and the one in the background gives out this LONG URL: http://uk.burberry.com/burberry/views/listing/searchResults.jsp?_dyncharset=UTF-8&frmSearch_txtQuery=&_D%3AfrmSearch_txtQuery=+&%2Fatg%2Fcommerce%2Fsearch%2Fcatalog%2FQueryFormHandler.errorURL=%2Fburberry%2Fviews%2Flisting%2FsearchResults.jsp&_D%3A%2Fatg%2Fcommerce%2Fsearch%2Fcatalog%2FQueryFormHandler.errorURL=+&start=1&_D%3Astart=+&_DARGS=%2Fburberry%2Fincludes%2FpageStart.jsp.frmSearch

Comment: Looking at it it could be related to Javascript or JSP issues on the page, which I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

No problem that I know of.  If you need to get the window to the foreground and **the typical way isn't working**, I sometimes use a JavaScript executor to bring the window to the front and then operate on it.

Comment: I used Javascript exceuter and that doesn't work aswell, also I normally test with 10 browser instances running at the same time locally on a machine. In the light of you mentioning there's nothing wrong with firefoxdriver, it could be something wrong with the makers of the website.